Here is a Bell's Theorem counterexample, what's wrong with it?
I wanted to understand Bell’s Theorem. I looked at explanations and I wasn’t sure I understood them.
I was not sure about statistical explanations. Probability theory is hard. It’s easy to do something which correctly solves a different problem from the one you think you're solving. There could be some assumption that doesn’t fit the thing we want to measure.
I saw a visual explanation. It claimed that a set of correlations have to fit a sawtooth wave (or something inside that wave, something with less area) and the correlations cannot be bigger.
!sawtooth]1

So I tried to make “reasonable” assumptions that would result in more correlation than that, and then ran simulations to see if I could make that happen. I thought I could see better what was going on with simulations that had clear assumptions.
I must have spent 40 hours coming up with weird patterns for the light to follow, and nothing worked. I could get the sawtooth wave, or I could get things that fit inside that wave. I quit.
A couple of years later I thought, what if I could find something that had the biggest possible correlation, and show that it could not violate Bell’s Theorem. Then our traditional model of photons could not fit, and we needed to start over with something different. Of course that’s what Bell’s theorem did, and the new photon theory was the something different. It was already done. But still I wanted to try it.
I didn’t care about exactly fitting how light works. If I could demonstrate that nothing could do it with broader assumptions, that was fine. If I could get something that didn’t fit the sawtooth pattern, then maybe there could be a way to do it that works for light too.
I did get something. Before I play with it much more, I want to ask whether there's something wrong with it. I could have programming errors. Maybe my model might have hidden assumptions that create invalid correlations. Maybe the explanation about the sawtooth pattern is wrong and doesn't really follow from Bell's theorem.
My model:
The experiment uses “filters” that can split light into two different parts that I’ll call “left” and “right”. When the light is polarized at one angle relative to the filter, all of it comes out “left”. Polarized 90 degrees different it all comes out “right”. In between, the light is split, like $sin^2$ and $cos^2$.
Light is made of little bits, and traditional experiments with light involved lots of them and we got statistical averages. I will call my little bits photans because they don’t act like real photons. Each photan has 3 "hidden variable" parameters. Those give it a deterministic outcome for any filter and the filter's angle. Everything interesting comes from the probability distributions of the parameters for many photans.
For each pair of filters with angles x and y, in simulation I put photans with identical properties through them, and note whether they come out the same or different. I keep a running total, I add one if they’re the same and subtract one if they’re different. The total divided by the number of successful trials is the “correlation” for that pair of filter angles.
I will assume that filters which are 180 degrees apart behave the same. I assume the light is always linearly polarized because circular polarized light will not get correlation with linear filters so I don’t want it.
So each photan has a parameter named $photan[0]$ that gives it a polarization angle. I consider only 180 degrees for photan angles, since I assume reverse angles behave the same. The distribution of photans will be uniform between angles [-pi/2, pi/2].
Second, each photan has a filter angle where it switches from coming out “left” to coming out “right”. That angle is not the same for all photans. They are created in a probability distribution. I would like that probability distribution to be set up so that the average angle comes out like light does, but I don’t care about that at the moment, not yet. The $photan[1]$ parameter sets that angle for a particular photan. I have $photan[1]$ more-or-less fit a gaussian distribution because that makes the correlations look nice. There's a slight complication involving comparing $photon[1]$ to the square of the cosine of the angular difference between the photon angle and the filter angle. I think it's easier to see how it works from the code than from a description here.


The third paramater,$photon[2]$, hides photans when a filter is too close to pi/4 distance from the photon angle $photon[0]$.
They aren't detected as "left" or "right". Maybe they are absorbed, or converted to a form that the sensor just doesn't pick up. And when one photan is not detected, the other is discarded and does not count toward correlations. When neither is detected, there is nothing to discard. This parameter fits a uniform distribution. When it is near one,the photan is mostly unaffected but may be lost when the filter is at close to a 45 degree angle compared to the photan angle. When it is near zero, the photan is detected only when the filter angle is very close to the photan angle, or close to 90 degrees apart. I set this parameter to fit a uniform distribution, so about half of the photans are not detected.


When I randomize photan parameters and pairs of filter angles, I get a correlation that approximates a sine wave.

When I set $photon[2]$ to zero so it has no effect, I get the usual sawtooth result.

When I change the distribution of the second hidden variable, the result of the third variable is much reduced.

How does it work?
Basicly, you usually get the linear sawtooth pattern because you set only the two filter angles, and you must let the photon polarization angle vary randomly. It turns out that anything you do that increases the correlation with one photon angle, decreases correlation at another angle. Everything cancels out except the linear difference between filter angles.
It turns out that with these particular hidden variables, more of the photans that would reduce the correlation get thrown away than photans that increase it, so the remaining ones show more correlation.
Of course light doesn't work this way. We discard half the light! But it does get higher correlation.
Here is the code. This site is run by reputable physicists and I believe it is safe.
code

Can you link the source about this saw tooth pattern? Im an amateur at this stuff and would like to learn a bit more.

Does photan[1] determine the outcome at some filters, but not at others? In reality, polarized light (without entangled pairs of photons) must be produced somehow. If you use a filter, this means photan[1] is a variable that gets added to a photan after passing the first filter (and before reaching the second). So, effectively, some photans have 2 hidden variables while others have 3.

Confuse-ray30, here is a link. I don't know that this author really knows what he claims, but his explanation looks clear. https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-Bells-theorem?share=1

Paul Kolk, the claim I have read is that this experiment produces pairs of photons that are guaranteed to behave the same, or guaranteed to behave differently. I am imagining two photons that are guaranteed to behave the same, and so they have the same value for photon[1]. I am not ready yet to think about how they might be changed by passing through a filter because for my present purposes I don't need to consider that. I don't want to assume that the photons produced this way are like the photons produced other ways. If I'm in a dead end I don't need to speculate too much about it.

This is closed since the question while asking for a standard answer is not itself standard physics. Can anyone suggest a place where it would be appropriate to ask the question?

@JThomas The real thing not only "produces pairs of photons that are guaranteed to behave the same", but also detects (nearly) all pairs. Your simulation discards them, which is an important difference. Multiply your results by the fraction that gets detected.

@Paul Kolk, Yes, that's a vital difference. My question is, first whether the "intuitive" explanation that the correlation must be sawtooth because of Bell's theorem is correct, and second whether it's allowable to discard some photons according to a deterministic plan that requires no pre-knowledge of x or y.

@JThomas The results of measurements must be binary . That means: you get one of two possible outcomes which you called "left" "right", not three, as in case of {left; right; discarded}.

Discarded results are not observed.
When you do two tests and only one outcome is observed, it is treated as background and thrown out. When you do two tests and no outcome is observed, you don't find out that anything happened. As I understand it, this is how the experiment works. It would  be possible to count the number of times you observe one outcome, and estimate that the number of discarded results must be low. But it does happen in practice.
